# Perl regex - match the previous character

Tags: regex, perl

I want to be able to do a regex on a string to add a backslash before a double quote, only when it doesn't already have a backslash before it.  So the function (e.g. regex_string) would have the output -

```
$my $string_1 = 'A "sentence';
regex_string($string_1); # Would equal 'A \"sentence'.  A backslash was added as one was not present.

$my $string_2 = 'A \"sentence';
regex_string($string_1); # Would equal 'A \"sentence'.  A backslash is not added because one already existed.
```

Can anyone help with how the regex should look?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex would match all the double quotes `"` which are not preceded by a backslash. Replacing the matched double quotes with `\\"` will give you the desired output.

Regex:

```
(?<!\\)(")
```

Replacement string:

```
\\\1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nH8eT5/6)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings = ('A "sentence', 'A\"sentence', '"A sentence');

for my $str(@strings) {
    $str =~ s/(?<!\\)(")/\\$1/g; 
    print $str, "\n";
}
```

Or the regex line would be like `$str =~ s/(?<!\\)"/\\"/g;`

**Output**

```
A \"sentence
A\"sentence
\"A sentence
```

Comment: This is called "negative lookbehind". You can read more about it here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

The regular expresion maybe: `s/[^\\]"|^"/\\"/g`. 
It looks for any character different of `\` preceding the `"`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings = ('A "sentence', 'A\"sentence', '"A sentence');

for my $str(@strings) {
    $str =~ s/[^\\]"|^"/\\"/g; 
    print $str, "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
A\"sentence
A\"sentence
\"A sentence
```

Answer (score 1):

It will put `\` before `"` and where backslash is not already in place,

```
$string =~ s|(?<! \\)(?= ")|\\|xg;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\\"|"
```

You can try this.

Replace by

`\\"`

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bZ8aY1/4

Answer (score 0):

Can a backslash escape itself?

Therefore the string `A \\"sentence` needs to have an additional backslash to escape the double quote?

If so, then the following implementation would work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $str = <DATA>) {
    $str =~ s/\\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?=")/\\/g; 
    print $str;
}

__DATA__
A "sentence
A\"sentence
"A sentence
A \\"sentence
A \\\"sentence
```

Outputs:

```
A \"sentence
A\"sentence
\"A sentence
A \\\"sentence
A \\\"sentence
```